# jQuery one image slide show problems

Tags: jquery, slideshow

So, I'm currently trying to build a site that has a giant one image slide show which is controlled by the nav tabs. I am trying to get the site to move the image (like a slide show) to a specific location when you click on a specific nav menu tab using jQuery. For some reason, nothing is happening. I'm almost positive the code is right, but maybe something is in the wrong position?...idk? HELP!

Here is a link to the current site:
http://mindhandle.com/UMCsite_v2/

Right now, only the "media" tab is targeted in the jQuery. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd recommend wrapping the `<a>` tags under the `<li>` elements in all the links that way you'll have a pointer cursor at each link, or add the CSS rule `cursor: pointer` to the li elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script error on the page you provided: `$ is not defined`.

[image]

You need to call `SS.js` ***AFTER*** you call jQuery scripts.

In your `head`, change the order to the following:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SS.js"></script>
```

---

`marginLeft` and `margin-left` would both be valid:

`.animate()` using `marginLeft` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/3FkLW/2/

`.animate()` using `margin-left` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/3FkLW/3/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting margin use left and top.

You'll have to set position: relative to image

Comment: This article on positioning sould help http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: It doesn't work because of the script error.... `marginLeft` or `margin-left` would be valid.